# Alpine Docker Image to run JLink executable

Tags: java, docker, gradle, libgdx, jlink

My current Docker image is approximately `200MB`. My goal is to reduce that as much as possible, so I thought the `alpine` image would be a great way to achieve that. However, I keep encountering roadblocks.

It's a multi-module libGDX project that uses Java 14 and its preview features, along with `JLink` (from `JPackage`) to produce a custom (lightweight) JRE.

I only care to deploy the `server` module, which depends on the `common` module (which the `client` module also uses).

I'll be providing all the necessary files below, but in case I'm missing something, here is a link to the repo: https://github.com/payne911/marvelous-bob/tree/dev

## Current problem

I either get:

- when executing `./server`: `file not found` for an executable file which **I know exists and is executable** where I'm trying to run it in the Docker Image
- when executing `apk add --no-cache someLibrary`: a `segfault: core dumped` when trying to download libraries in my `ENTRYPOINT` which I thought were required to execute that file (`libstdc++` and `libc6-compat`)

## Goal

Reusable lightweight Docker Image which contains everything to run libGDX executables generated by JLink.

## Current files which are in a working state and I'm trying to refactor

### `Dockerfile`

```
FROM openjdk:14-jdk-alpine
COPY server/build/libs/server-all.jar /app.jar
COPY utils/deploys/bootstrap.sh /bootstrap.sh
RUN chmod +x /bootstrap.sh
EXPOSE 80
ENTRYPOINT ["./bootstrap.sh"]
```

### `bootstrap.sh`

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
echo "========== LAUNCHING SERVER APP ========="
apk add --no-cache libstdc++
java --enable-preview -jar /app.jar
```

### `build.gradle` files

#### root

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
    }
}

// to force download of sources and JavaDoc
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'idea'
}
idea {
    module {
        downloadJavadoc = true
        downloadSources = true
    }
}

allprojects {

    version = '1.0'
    ext {
        appName = "marvelous-bob"
        gdxVersion = '1.9.10'
        roboVMVersion = '2.3.7'
        box2DLightsVersion = '1.5'
        ashleyVersion = '1.7.0'
        aiVersion = '1.8.2'

        slf4j = '1.7.26'
        logback = '1.2.3'
        lombok = '1.18.12'
        kryonet = '2.22.6'
        reflectionsVersion = '0.9.12'

        pieMenuVersion = '4.2.0'
        shapeDrawer = '2.3.0'
    }

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}

project(":desktop") {
    apply plugin: "java-library"


    dependencies {
        api project(":client")
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-tools:$gdxVersion"
    }
}

project(":client") {
    apply plugin: "java-library"


    dependencies {
        api project(":common")
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl:$gdxVersion"

        api "space.earlygrey:shapedrawer:$shapeDrawer"
        api "com.github.payne911:PieMenu:$pieMenuVersion"
    }
}

project(":server") {
    apply plugin: "java-library"


    dependencies {
        api project(":common")
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-headless:$gdxVersion"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
    }
}

project(":common") {
    apply plugin: "java-library"


    dependencies {
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
        api "com.badlogicgames.box2dlights:box2dlights:$box2DLightsVersion"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-ai:$aiVersion"

        // todo: do we need both logging libraries? p.s. kryonet uses Minlog
        api "org.slf4j:slf4j-api:$slf4j"
        api "ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:$logback"
        api "com.github.crykn:kryonet:$kryonet"
        api "org.reflections:reflections:$reflectionsVersion"
    }
}
```

#### common

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'io.freefair.lombok' version '5.1.0'
}

sourceCompatibility = 14
[compileJava, compileTestJava]*.options*.encoding = 'UTF-8'

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.compilerArgs += "--enable-preview"
}
tasks.withType(Test) {
    jvmArgs += "--enable-preview"
}
tasks.withType(JavaExec) {
    jvmArgs += '--enable-preview'
}

sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = [ "src/" ]

jar {
    from('src') {
        include '**/*.properties'
    }
}
```

#### server

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'io.freefair.lombok' version '5.1.0'
    id 'com.github.johnrengelman.shadow' version '5.2.0'
}

sourceCompatibility = 14
[compileJava, compileTestJava]*.options*.encoding = 'UTF-8'
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.compilerArgs += "--enable-preview"
}
tasks.withType(Test) {
    jvmArgs += "--enable-preview"
}
tasks.withType(JavaExec) {
    jvmArgs += '--enable-preview'
}
sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = [ "src/" ]

jar {
    project.version="" // to remove version number from the built jar's name
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.marvelousbob.server.BobServerLauncher'
    }
}
```

### GitHub Actions yml file

```
jobs:
  deploy:
    name: Deploy
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Setup with Java 14
        id: java-setup
        uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: 14

      - name: Allow GitHub Actions to run Gradlew
        run: chmod u+x gradlew

      - name: Run Gradle build
        id: gradle-build
        uses: eskatos/gradle-command-action@v1
        with:
          arguments: shadowJar

      # more stuff ...
```

## What I've tried

So many things, for days! Here was the state of my last attempt.

### `Dockerfile`

```
FROM alpine:3.7
COPY server/build/jpackage/server /server
FROM openjdk:14-jdk-alpine
COPY server/build/libs/server-all.jar /app.jar
COPY utils/deploys/bootstrap.sh /bootstrap.sh
RUN chmod +x /bootstrap.sh
EXPOSE 80
ENTRYPOINT ["./bootstrap.sh"]
```

### `bootstrap.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "========== LAUNCHING SERVER APP ========="
cd /server/bin
chmod +x server
./server
```

### `build.gradle`

#### root

Same as other one.

#### common

Same as other one.

#### server

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'io.freefair.lombok' version '5.1.0'
    id 'org.beryx.runtime' version '1.8.4'
}

sourceCompatibility = 14
[compileJava, compileTestJava]*.options*.encoding = 'UTF-8'
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.compilerArgs += "--enable-preview"
}
tasks.withType(Test) {
    jvmArgs += "--enable-preview"
}
tasks.withType(JavaExec) {
    jvmArgs += '--enable-preview'
}
sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = [ "src/" ]

mainClassName = "com.marvelousbob.server.BobServerLauncher"

task dist(type: Jar) {
    project.version="1" // adjust the CI/CD if you change this
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': project.mainClassName
    }
    from {
        configurations.compileClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
    with jar

    destinationDirectory = file("$buildDir/lib")
}

jpackageImage.dependsOn dist
dist.dependsOn classes

// JLink configuration to minimize size of generated jar
runtime {
    options = ['--strip-debug',
               '--compress', '2',
               '--no-header-files',
               '--no-man-pages',
               '--strip-native-commands',
               '--vm', 'server']
    modules = ['java.base' ,
               'java.desktop',
               'jdk.unsupported']
    distDir = file(buildDir)

    jpackage {
        //jpackageHome = '/usr/lib/jvm/open-jdk'
        mainJar = dist.archiveFileName.get()
    }
}
```

### Github Actions yml file

```
jobs:
  deploy:
    name: Deploy
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Setup with Java 14
        id: java-setup
        uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: 14

      - name: Building with Gradlew
        run: |
          chmod u+x gradlew
          ./gradlew server:jpackageImage

      # more stuff ...
```

Comment: So what was the solution you eventually found? I think I can guess what it is. I investigated something similar-sounding recently. Incidentally, this is the best, most well-documented question I've ever come across in 5+ years of using Stack Overflow! Good job!

Comment: @deduper I kept digging a bit after writing this question, but could never figure it out fully. It turns out some C libraries used by libGDX weren't included in the ``alpine`` image, so I added those in, and then I kept hitting other walls. It's mostly a question of properly configuring `alpine` for a software which uses OpenGL/LWJGL stuff, I think (but not certain).

Comment: Unlike most Linux distros, Alpine/Busybox-based ones use the [*`musl` C library*](https://www.musl-libc.org/faq.html). And *`musl`* is incompatible with the JDK/jlink; which are compiled with the [*`glibc`* library](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) for OpenJDK Linux builds. If Alpine is a must have, you'll have to find an image that's specifically built with *`glibc`*. They're out there. In fact the *`openjdk:14-jdk-alpine`* one in your first Dockerfile foots the bill I think. BTW, when you do *`./gradlew desktop:jre`* or *`./gradlew desktop:runtime`* what OS are you calling that on? TIA.

Comment: @deduper ``alpine`` is not required: it's just that I was aiming for a lightweight container. The point in using `jlink` is specifically to reduce the size of the JRE, so using a full JDK image defeats the purpose. Using `jpackage`, I wanted to include the trimmed-down JRE produced by `jlink` so that I do not need any JDK whatsoever on any image that would run this container.

Comment: I have been launching the container on a Linux headless server.

Comment: „*…I have been launching the container on a Linux headless server…*“ —  OK. But when you do *`./gradlew desktop:jre`* or *`./gradlew desktop:runtime`* you aren't ***launching*** the container with those commands. Are you? Those commands ***create*** the *`jlink`* / *`jpackage`* jre and runtime respectively. Right?  Isn't ***launching*** what's happening as a result of executing your *`bootsrap.sh`* file: *`./server`*? What ***distro*** of Linux are you on when you call those two ***creation*** commands: (***1***) *`./gradlew desktop:jre`* (***2***) *`./gradlew desktop:runtime`*? TIA.

Comment: @deduper Ouch, okay. This Dockerfile gets processed by AWS ECS, to be more precise. But ECS indeed calls `bootstrap.sh` to launch the server.. The *actual* CI/CD code that is run is shown in [this file](https://github.com/payne911/marvelous-bob/blob/dev/.github/workflows/aws.yml): it published on DockerHub, and then updates the JSON configuring ECS's image uri to point to that. Ultimately, after having its JSON updated, `bootstrap.sh` is called to launch the service task. The Linux distro would be in the AWS documentation... they use some custom stuff most probably.

Comment: „*Ouch*“ — Didn't intend it that way. Sry. I'm only trying to reproduce your errors. — „*This Dockerfile gets processed by AWS ECS*“ —  So you never directly call *`./gradlew server:jpackageImage`* or *`./gradlew server:jpackage`* on your local machine? Long story short: This „[*`runs-on: ubuntu-latest`*](https://github.com/payne911/marvelous-bob/blob/dev/.github/workflows/aws.yml#L17)“ is more than likely behind your „*`./server: file not found`*“. I've seen that before when running a runtime on Alpine that was built on Ubuntu. I've successfully built + started your server runtime on Alpine.

Comment: @deduper no worries, no offense taken. However, the thing is that this is from a few months ago, and since my attempts only lead to failures, I ended up keeping my ``shadowJar`` approach. Now my memory is failing me a bit. Since you're actually interested in this issue (and I am too), maybe we should move into a chat? (I'm not sure how to create a link for a SO-chat room, though. I think SO will just propose us a link pretty soon.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222569/discussion-between-deduper-and-payne).

Answer (score 0):

@deduper seems to have figured it out (see https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222569/discussion-between-deduper-and-payne), but I didn't have time to go back and make sure his analysis is right.

In theory, it does make a lot of sense, so I'm posting it nonetheless as an answer:

> I'm pretty sure the main cause of the errors you describe in your question is because you built the runtime on either Windows 10 or Ubuntu; then tried to deploy and run the runtime on Alpine.

I won't accept my answer because I haven't made a confirmation of this yet, but I'm nonetheless posting it in case others encounter this problem and want a probable clue.